# d3.js treemap new data doesn't render

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

This is my first attempt at d3.js and I can't figure out how to redraw the treemap.  I am trying to load new data into the [treemap example](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/examples/treemap) using a json request.  I've added the following code to my treemap.js.

```
d3.select(".search_field").on("click", function(){
    d3.json("/applications.json?search=Applejuice", function(json) {
        div.data([json]).selectAll("div")
            .data(treemap.nodes)
            .enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "cell")
            .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .call(cell);
   }); 
});
```

I've inspected var div after the request completes and the data is loaded in the object correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending new elements instead of updating the existing ones. The line

```
.enter().append("div")
```

takes care of this and should be deleted if you want to update the existing data. Calling `.enter()` after `.data()` will give you the data that previously wasn't there, `.exit()` the data that is not there anymore. If you find that the old and the new data aren't merged correctly, you can use the optional second argument to `.data()` to supply a merge function.

Comment: Lars, Thank you so much for your reply. Removing .enter().append("div") helped but I also had to add treemap.sticky(true); before the div.data section.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon. When I try loading data that has very similar values I get the following behavior [screencast](http://www.screencast.com/t/bmHTYNGXx). I didn't quite follow the whole .enter() .exit() calls.

Comment: As I've said, you might need to use the optional function argument to `.data()` and merge by ID or something like that.